# what is the correct way to use flexigrid onError

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I looked around and found that there is an onerror function for flexigrid but I can seem to find how to use it andy have any idea how to use it so I don't have to mod the flexigrid.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all that needs to be done is for to define it in flexigrid options

```
$('#flex').fliexigrid({
  onError: function(data){
       // do stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
onError: function (data){ 
   for (var i in data){ 
      alert("Header: " + i +"\nMessage: " + data[i]); 
    } 
}
```